# Help with limits algebraically

Tags: calculus, limits

The question I am working on is evaluating $$ \lim_{x \rightarrow 5}\; \frac{x^2 - 6x + 5}{x - 5}$$ While I understand that the first step is to get the $x - 5$ out of the denominator so $5$ can be plugged in, I do not know how to manipulate the formula  to do that. Any information manipulating formulas would be extremely helpful

Comment: Have you tried plugging $x=5$ into the numerator?

Comment: Note $5$ is a root of the numerator. So it is equal to $(x-5)(ax+b)$. Find $a,b$ the way you want, there are many. Then simplify the fraction.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Note the convenient fact that the numerator $\,(x^2 - 6x + 5)\,$ factors very nicely for us in this case, giving us:

$$\frac{x^2 - 6x +5}{x-5}=\frac{(x-5)(x-1)}{(x-5)} = (x-1)$$

$$\textrm{Hence,}\quad\lim_{x\to5}\; \frac{x^2 - 6x +5}{x-5} = \lim_{x\to 5}\; (x-1) = 4$$

The fact that the original function is not defined at $\,x = 5\,$ is of no importance because when taking the limit as $x \to 5$, we are interested only in the behavior of the function as $x$ gets very, very close to $5$, not what is happening precisely AT $5$.

---

Comment: You are correct, it was supposed to be x^2 - 6x + 5 and factoring it works. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

$$\displaystyle \lim_{x \rightarrow 5} \frac{x^2 - 6x + 5}{x - 5}=\lim_{x\to 5}\frac{2x-6}{1}=2\cdot 5-6=4.$$

I used L'Hospital rule.